# Redis keys command not showing all keys

Tags: java, caching, redis, cache-control, jedis

I am using redis as my caching layer, In that, i have a bunch of places where i am using @Cacheable in my different services and layers.

Here is the sample code:

```
@Cacheable(value = "my_detail", key = "'m_detail_'+#entityIdd")
public InstituteDetail getMyDetail(Long entityId) {

    call1();
    call2()
}

@Cacheable(value = "call_1", key = "'call_1'+#entityIdd")
public InstituteDetail getMyDetail1(Long entityId) {

    //some code
}

@Cacheable(value = "call_2", key = "'call_2'+#entityIdd")
public InstituteDetail getMyDetail2(Long entityId) {

    //some code
}
```

The application and caching works fine, but when i get all the keys in redis-cli using the following command:

```
keys *
```

it only show the keys for call_1 and call_2. **And does not shows the key for "my_detail".**

This is weird and not getting resolved. Any suggestion what's wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a proxy class generated that intercepts all requests and responds with the cached value,only the external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that within the target object calling another method of the same target object, will not lead to an actual cache interception at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with `@Cacheable`.

Hence **you can't store the value 'my_detail' in cache** if the method calls the other methods of **same class**.